# Symfony Undefined variable (contexterror exception) when array empty in controller

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Here is the thing. A trainer can speak zero to many languages. I want to display the languages for one or several trainers on a page. Note that I'm working on a code I didn't start from scratch.

In my controller :

```
foreach ($trainers as $trainer){
$trainer_entity = $doctrine->getRepository('AppBundle:Trainer')->find($trainer["id"]);

 $listLangues = $this->getDoctrine()
->getManager()
->getRepository('AppBundle:TrainerLangues')
->findByTrainer_id($trainer["id"]);
 }
return [
'user' => $user,
'listLangues' => $listLangues,
'trainers' => $trainers,
];
```

In my twig file:

```
{% if listLangues %}
<b>Langues</b> :
 {% for l in listLangues %}
         {{ l.langue.name }}
           {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
```

This works when the person is linked to languages, so listLangues not empty.

Otherwise I get

> Notice: Undefined variable: listLangues 500 Internal Server Error -
>   ContextErrorException

I tried `{% if listLangues is defined %}` as well, but the system seems to block in the controller. It never happened to me before.

note that initializing `$listLangues` only leads to no display on the twig page.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

what do you really want to display in your view?

Here is a simple tips, you could try in your controller:

```
/***/
public function yourAction()
{
    return $this->render('your-template.html.twig', [
        'user' => $this->getUser(),
        'trainers' => $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Trainer::class)->findAll()
    ]);
}
/***/
```

Then, in your view (basic implementation)

```
{% for trainer in trainers %}
  <h4>{{ trainer.name }}</h4>
  {% if trainer.languages %}
  <ul>
      {% for language in trainer.languages %}
          <li>{{ language.name }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope, it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate `$listLangue`s because if there isn't trainers the variable can't exist and code is broke.

Try to add this before your foreach:

```
$listLangues = null;
```

Or instantiate It with a value or what you want but declare It before your foreach to be sure that exists

Comment: thanks, your your reply, but that's what I meant when I said I tried initialising it. Weirdly enought, the page doesn't display any of the variables. No error message, but not the rest either !

Answer (score 0):

If your array `$trainers` is empty, the foreach nevers loops so the `$listLangues` var is never defined.

Try declaring it as an empty array BEFORE the foreach :

```
$listLangues = array();
```

Comment: thanks, but I tried that already, same result as instantiating $listlangues, nothing is displayed !

Comment: @SandrineOciepka That's normal behavior : your `$listLangues` wasn't defined because of the `foreach` not looping. Declaring it as an empty array prevents the `Undefined variable` error, it won't fetch any data.

With a valid mapping (many-to-many relation between `Trainer` and `TrainerLangue`) the answer by scoolnico should do want you want